# Android Compatible Devices (non phone)

Tags: android

I'm interested in playing around with the Android OS, but I do not need or want a phone.

It doesn't look like there are any 'non-phone' Android devices out there, so maybe there's a device that is compatible that I can flash.

Any ideas?

Comment: Move question to http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/. More Appropriate there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search for [Android tablet](http://www.google.com/search?&q=android+tablet) reveals the existence of several such devices.

Comment: Thanks to all - I marked this one as the answer because I didn't know how to find it. "Android Tablet" was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

they sell them at Kmart. http://tech.fortune.cnn.com/2010/08/06/attention-kmart-shoppers-149-android-tablet-on-aisle-5/?section=magazines_fortune

Answer (score 1):

There are some pads, e.g. those made by [Archos](http://www.archos.com/), which run Android but cost significantly less than a phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to play with the os, you could try the Android emulator which ships as part of the Android SDK (free).